# How to get all my data from model to JSON? I need export and import my data

Tags: django

How to get all my data from model to JSON? I need export and import my data

Is there any command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) command to dump data in your table. By default it gives in JSON format.

You can do in command line, to print data on screen.

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Rohan, you need the [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) command.

I generally do an app at a time, output to file, and add an indent to the output to make it more readable -

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata --indent 2 myapp > /path/to/myapp/fixtures/my_data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

First create fixtures folder inside your app.

Dump all models data of the app:

```
 python manage.py dumpdata --format=json --indent=4 [app_name] > [app_name]/fixtures/initial_data.json
```